# Use custom variable and in steps in Cloudbuild GCP

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I am trying to use custom variable in `cloudbuild.yaml` that variables describes `git version of release`. How could I use this variable in steps and bind my docker tag with this release.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    args: [ 'describe', '--tags --always --dirty' ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '--tag=gcr.io/${_BUILDER}/${_REPO_ID}:$REVISION_ID', '--file=Dockerfile', '.' ]
    dir: ${_BASE_DIR}
substitutions:
  _BASE_DIR:
  _REPO_ID: "repo-id"
  _BUILDER: "builder-id"
  _CUSTOM_TAG_NAME:
```

I want to write tag name received from `'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'` and write to `_CUSTOM_TAG_NAME` this I want to use while tagging my image. `$REVISION_ID` is giving me some random string that's irrelevant to recognize build rather git describe me with valid last release this way `v2022.2.61-27-g8a23c87-dirty`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it's the only bad and boring side of Cloud Build. You have to do a hack to achieve that. Look at that piece of code

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    entrypoint: bash
    args: 
      - -c
      - |
        git describe --tags --always --dirty > /workspace/git_info.data

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: bash
    args: 
      - -c
      - |
          REVISION_ID="${_CUSTOM_TAG_NAME}-$(cat /workspace/git_info.data)"
          docker build --tag=gcr.io/${_BUILDER}/${_REPO_ID}:$$REVISION_ID --file=Dockerfile . 
    dir: ${_BASE_DIR}
substitutions:
  _BASE_DIR:
  _REPO_ID: "repo-id"
  _BUILDER: "builder-id"
  _CUSTOM_TAG_NAME:
```

2 things:

- firstly, you have to write the data got from one steps in a file in a persistent storage between the steps (the `/workspace` directory). And get the content in the subsequent steps with a `cat` (sometime you gave to perform a `cat ... | head -1` to skip the trailing new line)
- then, you have to use the double $$ to get the local bash variable (and not the substitutions variables)